# Windows Server 2003 Standard - programs compatibility?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, windows, application

I'm wondering if, first, if the Windows Server 2003 GUI looks like Windows XP?  Second, do regular programs that run on XP also run on Server 2003?  Or are there special programs written for them?  How does all that work?  Thanks!

Comment: Your bio says "Computer geek. specializing in Windows and Zune.", yet you ask such a question? Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @John: sorry, I should say that I specialize in Windows XP, Vista, and 7, because I know nothing about servers, whether they be Windows or Linux...I'm just now trying out servers and learning more about what they do...does that clear things up?  :-)   how should I phrase that?  (knowing more about Windows OS than server OS?)

Comment: Considering what this site is for it would be expected that anyone with Windows experience would be familiar with Windows servers. After all, servers are what it's all about.

Comment: but it is also a place to learn about servers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2003's GUI is the same as XP's 'Classic' GUI. It's possible to hack on the uitheme.dll 'shiny stuff' to 2003, but not often done. This gets better in Windows Server 2008 as you can install the 'Desktop Experience' option and get a desktop similar to Vista.

2003's program and driver support is pretty much in-line with XP. Most printer and device drivers that work on XP will also work on 2003, with a few exceptions. Programs work in almost all cases.